# Unknown plugin in babelrc when running jest

Tags: jestjs, babel-jest, parceljs

I have a project that works using Parcel to build and Babel to transpile.

When I try to run jest, I get

```
Test suite failed to run
ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "syntax-dynamic-import" specified in "/app/.babelrc" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "/app"
```

The plugin is found successfully when running normally through Parcel, and is listed in my package.json's dependencies & installed.

My babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/syntax-dynamic-import",
  ],
    "env": {
    "test": {
      "plugins": ["dynamic-import-node"]
    }
  }
}
```

In package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.6.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.0",
    "less": "^2.0.0",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.10.3",
    "parcel-plugin-eslint": "^1.0.4"
  },
```

The full project code can be found [on Glitch](https://glitch.com/~casseys-hooks). Remix the project to get your own version that you can edit and attempt to run scripts on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got [the following response when I posted this as a bug in the Jest GitHub repo](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/8065#issuecomment-473957314).

In .babelrc, my plugin should be defined like this:

```
@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import
```

and since I'm using Jest 23, I need to install `babel-core@bridge` to use babel@7 or I can upgrade to Jest 24.